# CheckBoxList in a complex view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have searched here many times but I could not find what I want.
I am developing an application where I have USERS with specific Skills, and I want to relate them to specific project.

So I have the following tables: Users, UserSkills and more
My question is: I am using CRUD in MVC4, and when I open the EDIT view from the UserDetail Controller, in order to edit the user information, I need also to add (in the same Edit view) partial view, or any mechanism, where I list the user skills, using CheckBoxes to help in multi-selecting various skills for this user, and then when pressing "Save" it should store the User and UserSkills information back to the dB (MS-SQL).

I am using this Model:

```
public class SkillsViewModel
    {
        public IList<Skill> AvailableSkills { get; set; }
        public IList<Skill> SelectedSkills { get; set; }
        public SavedSkills SevedSkills { get; set; }
        public User Usr { get; set; }
    }
```

SavedSkills are the UserSkills Table, which will be used for the dB
AvailableSkills are the Skills Table
SelectedSkills are the ones that are selected in the Edit view

Keeping in mind that the Edit view also contain an image upload file:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(User Usr, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            #region//validate file is selected
            if (file != null)
            {
                if (file.ContentLength > (512 * 1000)) // 512 KB
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("FileErrorMessage", "File size 
                             must be within 512KB");
                }
                string[] allowedType = new string     
                          []"image/png", "image/gif", 
                              "image/jpg", "image/jpeg" };
                bool isFileTypeValid = false;
                foreach (var i in allowedType)
                {
                    if (file.ContentType == i.ToString())
                    {
                        isFileTypeValid = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!isFileTypeValid)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError 
                       ("FileErrorMessage", "Only .png, 
                            .gif and .jpg file allowed");
                }
            }
            #endregion
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (Skk.Skk.Count (x => x.IsSelected) == 0)
                {
                    //return "You have not selected any City";
                }
                else
                {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.Append("You selected - ");
                    foreach (Skill skilll in Skk.Skk)
                    {
                        if (skilll.IsSelected)
                        {
                            sb.Append(skilll.SkillName + ", ");
                        }
                    }
                    //sb.Remove(sb.ToString().LastIndexOf(","), 1);
                    //return sb.ToString();
                }


                //Update User
                if (file != null)
                {
                    string savePath = Server.MapPath("~/Pictures");
                    string fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension
                             (file.FileName);
                    file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(savePath, fileName));
                    Usr.ImagePath = fileName;
                }


                using (dBEntities dc = new dBEntities())
                {
                    var v = dc.Users.Where(a => a.Id.Equals
                            (Usr.Id)).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (v != null)
                    {
                        v.UserName = Usr.UserName;
                        v.Email = Usr.Email ;
                        v.StartDate = Usr.StartDate ;
                        v.Company = Usr.Company ;
                        v.Position = Usr.Position;
                        v.Division = Usr.Division ;
                        v.Department = Usr.Department ;
                        v.PM = Usr.PM ;
                        v.AM = Usr.AM;
                        v.Permissions = Usr.Permissions;
                        v.IsActive = Usr.IsActive;
                        if (file != null)
                        {
                            v.ImagePath = Usr.ImagePath ;
                        }
                    }
                    dc.SaveChanges();
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.Department = new SelectList
                   (db.Departments, "DepID", "DepName", Usr.Department);
            ViewBag.Division = new SelectList
                  (db.Divisions, "DivID", "DivName", Usr.Division);
            ViewBag.Position = new SelectList
                  (db.Positions, "PosID","PosName", Usr.Position);
            return View(Usr);
        }
```

I hope I have explained it well, and thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to show the view! Your view model seems wrong for the scenario you have described.If your wanting to display/select skills for a user, then you need a view model to represent Skills (e.g. ID, Name, IsSelected) and a view model to edit them ( User and List<SkillViewModel>)

Answer (score 0):

I had same situation with you.
I was used chosen to add user's skills. IMHO, it more user friendly then using checkboxes (you can look chosen in action in linked-in, when you add your skills) when you have more than 20 skills in your database. 
Chosen is regular HTML "select" tag with multiple attribute but more beautiful. 
I also use Ajax JQuery to post my data to controller.

JQuery POST method also support send form data with attached file.
So you don't need to change your Edit action a lot. What you need is add parameter for selected skills (it's a string which separated by comma).